Oracle gives incorrect statistics for a newly created index
I'm using oracle 19c
I have a table containing around 50M of records
I have the following query
 select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */  id  from MY_TABLE mytable WHERE
 mytable.STARTDATE <= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY') AND mytable.ENDDATE >= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY');

It gives the following plan
SQL_ID  98f475hv01xwg, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select   /*+ gather_plan_statistics */           id from 
MY_TABLE mytable  WHERE  mytable.STARTDATE <= 
to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY') AND mytable.ENDDATE >= 
to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY')
 
Plan hash value: 1075412610
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                       |      1 |        |     50 |00:00:00.02 |      28 |     15 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| MY_TABLE              |      1 |     33M|     50 |00:00:00.02 |      28 |     15 |  1028K|  1028K| 3096K (0)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - storage(("MYTABLE"."ENDDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2024-03-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "MYTABLE"."STARTDATE"<=TO_DATE(' 
              2024-03-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))
       filter(("MYTABLE"."ENDDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2024-03-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "MYTABLE"."STARTDATE"<=TO_DATE(' 
              2024-03-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))

Why is the expected rows (33M) much bigger than the actual rows?from where oracle is getting this statistics?
I have than decided to create an index on the COLUMN ENDDATE:
create index MY_TABLE_TEST on MY_TABLE(ENDDATE);

I have run the same query but oracle is still using full table access!
I have than added a hint to force my new index:
 select  /*+ INDEX(mytable,MY_TABLE_TEST) */
      /*+ gather_plan_statistics */
 id  from MY_TABLE mytable
 
WHERE  mytable.STARTDATE <= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY')
AND mytable.ENDDATE >= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY');

And I got the following plan:
SQL_ID  0knxk82yhkruw, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ INDEX(mytable,MY_TABLE_TEST) */  /*+ 
gather_plan_statistics */            id  from 
MY_TABLE mytable  WHERE  mytable.STARTDATE <= 
to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY') AND mytable.ENDDATE >= 
to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY')
 
Plan hash value: 2267489923
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                       | E-Rows |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                            |        |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MY_TABLE      |     33M|
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | MY_TABLE_TEST |     33M|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("MYTABLE"."STARTDATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2024-03-20 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
   2 - access("MYTABLE"."ENDDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2024-03-20 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
 
Note
-----
   - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
       * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
       * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level

I was surprised :

Why I'm no longer getting A-Rows column like in the first query
Why is my index range scan expecting the same 33M records although in reality, it should return only few thousands of records-this is a new index I was expecting to get accurate statistics


Oracle uses statistics it has already gathered to predict cardinalities from each row source in a query as it puts together its plan. You can view these statistics in dba_tab_statistics and dba_tab_col_statistics. Lacking these, it can also use dynamic sampling to read a portion of the table at parse time in order to extrapolate the missing statistics.
You are asking for all rows current as of a given date, which means two different date columns (start and end) have to be considered in relationship to each other, not independently. This is very hard for Oracle to predict, because it doesn't store in any normal statistics the relative difference between two columns. It doesn't know if most of your rows are active for years, or active for only minutes. If only minutes, it would predict a small result. If for years, it would predict a very large result. All it knows is that there are a ton of rows with a start date earlier than your 2024 date and a ton of rows with an end date later than our 2024 date, so it's just multiplying the two probabilities and over-estimating. This kind of thing happens all the time. The optimizer isn't perfect, as statistics don't tell it everything.
The reason why your index isn't being used is because Oracle believes you will get 33 million rows - that's far too many rows relative to the whole table to justify the much less efficient index access. If you were to correct its estimate of the # of rows and it knew there were only 50, it would use the index.
You can either hint the query with a cardinality or opt_estimate hint to correct its assumptions:
 select  /*+ cardinality(mytable,50) */
     id  from MY_TABLE mytable
  WHERE  mytable.STARTDATE <= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY')
    AND mytable.ENDDATE >= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY');

 select  /*+ opt_estimate(table mytable rows=50) */
     id  from MY_TABLE mytable
  WHERE  mytable.STARTDATE <= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY')
    AND mytable.ENDDATE >= to_date('20032024','DDMMYYYY');

... or you can play around with extended statistics on a column group and see if that helps:
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'MY_TABLE','(STARTDATE,ENDDATE)') 
  from dual

To your last question, your second example is trying to provide two separate hint blocks. You can only have one per query block, so the second one is being ignored.
